# Implemeting phonetic search in Dynamics CRM

Tags: search, crm, microsoft-dynamics

How can I enable phonetic search in Dynamics CRM 2015 on-premise? By phonetic search I mean that the search results will contain also similarly sounding words e.g. Meier, Mayer...

Answer (score 0):

You can't, that isn't a feature of CRM. You would need to build some custom search app to achieve that.